# Play sound when dateTime in listView == dateTime.Now

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, datetime, audio

I am trying to do playing sound when DateTime in ListView.Items is equal to DateTime.Now.
My code is:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.View = View.Tile;
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Groups.Add(pilne);
        listView1.Groups.Add(przyszle);
        DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            if (item.SubItems[2].Text == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMMM/yyyy"))
            {
                SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\Alarm01.wav");
                simpleSound.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

and my second form is:

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy";
        dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
        dateTimePicker2.ShowUpDown = true;

    }
```

I am adding items from second form like this:

```
private void btn2Zapisz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data2 = dateTimePicker1.Text;        //date
        string godzina2 = dateTimePicker2.Text;     //time
        string nazwa2 = tB2Nazwa.Text;              //name
        string opis2 = rTB2Opis.Text;               //description
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(nazwa2);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(data2);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(godzina2);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(opis2);
        var dataWybrana = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        var dataAktualna = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        string lvi2 = lvi.ToString();

        if (dataWybrana < dataAktualna)
        {
            listViewForm2.Items.Add(lvi);
            lvi.Group = pilne2;
        }
        else
        {
            listViewForm2.Items.Add(lvi);
            lvi.Group = przyszle2;
        }
        for (int i = listViewForm2.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ListViewItem itm = listViewForm2.SelectedItems[i];
            listViewForm2.Items[itm.Index].Remove();
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Its not playing sound. I want play sound when lvi.SubItems.Add(data2) is equal to current date. Whats wrong in this code?

Comment: Have you tested that `item.SubItems[2].Text == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMMM/yyyy")` equates to true? It is failing to play the sound or failing the if statement?

Comment: `item.SubItems[2].Text == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MMMM.yyyy")`
is failing to play sound

Comment: So, yes, the if statement does correctly return true?

Comment: I think it doesnt.

Comment: Put a breakpoint there in your debugger and find out for sure. If it does not result to true when you expect it to then you'll need to adjust the date formatting most likely. With the breakpoint you can make sure the two values are resulting in the same datetime string.

Comment: I think its not working because if statement is before I add items to listview.

Comment: That would do it. Move your foreach loop to a separate function and call it after the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the sound is loaded before playing

```
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\Alarm01.wav");
simpleSound.Load();
simpleSound.Play();
```

Also, you may want to have the sound file stored in the app as a resource. Then you can reference it like this.

```
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Alarm01);
simpleSound.Play();
```

This would avoid issues of the sound file not being found due to permissions issues, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well the code looks fine but playing sound really depend on the environment that you are working on 
For example your are doing this code on a windows server (let say 2012) then in-order to play  play sound you need to enable media feature from control panel / add or remove feature or you need proper access rights(resx will help).
there are certain thing that you can

1.You can try to play some other audio files in the production environment to mark sure that the production environment can make some noise. In other words, mark sure that the production environment can emit sound.

2.You can try to use the Windows Media Player to play the .wav file in the production environment to check if the .wav file is a bad file or not.
You can try to run the app in other computer, such as other desktop and other computer with same environment with the “production environment” you have tested.

3.You can try to add some log info and “try…catch…” statement in the code your app to check if there are some exceptions occurs when you are running the app in the production environment.